# how to export svg with only lines in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, svg

i need to have the design of my project in lines, polygon,and polyline, but it makes them paths, it's possible to doit withouth editing the svg code directly?

Answer (score 1):

Option A:

At least my illustrator version.

1. Illustrator will export  `<line>` elements  made as a single span segment with no tangents and is never touched with convert anchor tool.
2. Illustrator exports `<polygon>` if the shape you use is closed and has no tangent handles.
3. Illustrator exports `<polyline>` if element is made out of a multispand segment with no tangents and is never touched with convert anchor tool.

Option B: you can make your own SVG exporter. If you document is limited in features than its not so hard.

- See [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73629/create-2-morphable-svgs/73636#73636) for a example that you can use to expand to your needs. (It dies exactly the opposite of your need, iy outputs all polylines as paths)

Option C: use a external software like web JavaScript that fixes this for you. Web is littered with examples.