From drawing to code
I know how to write the code (*.jsx) that will draw a path in Illustrator. By path I mean a number of path points (anchor point, pair of direction points, ...).
BUT is there a way to ‘get’ the location of .Anchor, .LeftDirection, .RightDirection. from a selected path? So, from drawing to code...

Yes, obviously. Have you read the programming reference? Depending on what you need you may not need to do this at all, both EPS, PDF and SVG dumps this to a text file to begin with so if all you need is points out don't bother. Anyway, not having too much time to write an answer, there is a special SVG dumper that I have written that shows you what you need in the post: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73629/create-2-morphable-svgs/73636#73636 Should get you there.

If you want something human readable, export it as an SVG, then open the SVG in a text editor.  The syntax for SVG paths is shown and explained here: https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/

Excellent. This in combination with SVG Path Visualizer (https://svg-path-visualizer.netlify.app/) does the trick.
